# Cannot Write Data to My External Disk When I Give Executable Permission

Tags: 16.04, mount, disk, disk-utility

I wanted to store Android SDK on my external hard drive. I added location, which is `/media/erayerdin/ERDIN_EXT1/sources/sdk/linux_x64/android`, to my `PATH` variable by editing `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

However, I came across an issue. My drive did not have an execution permission. Even `chmod` could not solve the problem. So, I looked up a little bit on internet and solved this issue by manually editing partition options in Gnome Disks Utility as below:

[image]

Briefly, I set *Automatic Mount Options* to *off*, added `exec` to the options and changed *Mount Point* for `PATH` variable. I added `rw` option later, just to see if it would work, but it did not.

While `Automatic Mount Options` is turned off, I simply cannot create neither folders nor files, which also affects Android SDK to be not able to download SDK files and tools.

I can overcome this problem by accessing the disk with root privileges. However, I do not want this. I want to execute, read and write *things* in disk as a normal user.

What to do?

---

## Environment

- Ubuntu 16.04
- **Disk Format:** fat32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My drive did not have an execution permission. Even chmod could not solve the problem

Those 2 only work on a filesystem that is POSIX compliant (ext2/3/4, reiserfs and the like; none of the Microsoft filesystems though). If not chmod can not work. And then execute permissions also need to be set when mounting.

---

> fat32

is not POSIX compliant.

- you need mount option `users` to allow others than root to mount and unmount.
- you need mount option `umask=000` for RWX permissions for user, group and others. (umask works the other way around from chmod so umask 000 = chmod 777). Lower permissions to `umask=007` or `umask=077` to lock out group and others.

Comment: However, the execution permission is gone again. My options are, in order, `nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show,exec,rw,users,umask=000`. Does order matter or does it conflict with another option?

Comment: hmm good one. as far as I know order does not matter.

Comment: Yes, now it works like a charm. Thanks. I moved `exec` option at the very end. My current options look like `nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show,rw,users,umask=000,exec`.

Comment: so it does matter? :D never knew. mind that there is also uid=user and gid=users  as options for user and group.